# How to train TensorFlow network using a generator to produce inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The TensorFlow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) describe a bunch of ways to read data using TFRecordReader, TextLineReader, QueueRunner etc and queues.

What I would like to do is much, much simpler:  I have a python generator function that produces an infinite sequence of training data as (X, y) tuples (both are numpy arrays, and the first dimension is the batch size).  I just want to train a network using that data as inputs.

Is there a simple self-contained example of training a TensorFlow network using a generator which produces the data?  (along the lines of the MNIST or CIFAR examples)

Comment: There is [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), which might be useful for your case.

Comment: An [example of `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3fca8afe7eaaaa845b803ab7951ee3f3ed235208/official/transformer/translate.py#L112-L117)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Suppose you have a function that generates data:

```
 def generator(data): 
    ...
    yield (X, y)
```

Now you need another function that describes your model architecture. It could be any function that processes X and has to predict y as output (say, neural network).

Suppose your function accepts X and y as inputs, computes a prediction for y from X in some way and returns loss function (e.g. cross-entropy or MSE in the case of regression) between y and predicted y:

```
 def neural_network(X, y): 
    # computation of prediction for y using X
    ...
    return loss(y, y_pred)
```

To make your model work, you need to define placeholders for both X and y and then run a session:

```
 X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, x_dim))
 y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, y_dim))
```

Placeholders are something like "free variables" which you need to specify when running the session by `feed_dict`:

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
     # variables need to be initialized before any sess.run() calls
     tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

     for X_batch, y_batch in generator(data):
         feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch} 
         _, loss_value, ... = sess.run([train_op, loss, ...], feed_dict)
         # train_op here stands for optimization operation you have defined
         # and loss for loss function (return value of neural_network function)
```

Hope you would find it useful. However, bear in mind this is not fully working implementation but rather a pseudocode since you specified almost no details.

Comment: is there a way to pass the generator function to an estimator model, rather than manually coding the next function?

Comment: @skadoosh I think you should consider using Keras.

Comment: @skadoosh - if you want to use tensorflow, version 1.6 allows `Estimator.train` to accept a `tf.data.Dataset`, which can be made with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`.

Comment: I write my code according to your solution. However, my `.meta` file is growing bigger and bigger while training, and my training speed is slowing down rapidly. I guess some new ops is being added to model graph. I thought it may result from `yield`. Any idea? I'm in huge pain on this problem...

Comment: What about the validation data? Since we might need to perform a validation after each epoch, we shall use another generator at the same time for validation. How ?!

Comment: note this comment is valid for tensorflow 1, as tensorflow 2 does not have Session anymore