# Preparing images to feed into tensorflow as datasets

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

## AskTensorFlow

I have used the tensorflow packaged datasets like MNIST, IMDB to study the working of tensorflow. However, in practical applications we have to preprocess and prepare the dataset on our own. Suppose I am working with image dataset, so I want to preprocess them to a format that can be fed into a tensorflow model. How can I preprocess image dataset to a tensorflow format?

Answer (score 1):

When working with images, you will usually use a generator. 
Generator is a function which output `(u,v)`, where `u` are the samples, and `v` are the labels.

Example on how to do this can be found here [How to train TensorFlow network using a generator to produce inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325275/how-to-train-tensorflow-network-using-a-generator-to-produce-inputs).

When building the generator function to deal with image, remember that every image is just an array, of either `(x,y)` for greyscale, or `(x,y,channels)` for color image. 
Thus your generator function will need to read a batch of images from the disk, and turn them into arrays. there are plenty of tools to handle this: [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) , [scipy](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/), [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/tutorial.html).
After loading the images you can do any manipulations you like on them (using these tools, or others), usualy you will need to **reshape** the image to fit your model. 
In the end you will need to output a pair `([batch_size,x,y,channels], [batch_size,labels])`.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know how it turned out. Thanks

Comment: @AnandNautiyal How did it turn out? What did you do specifically?